# What is the Nethereum analog of "web3.version.network"?

Tags: nethereum, c#

I am just getting started with Nethereum and I want to ensure I am connected to the correct network.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found it: "web3.Net.Version"

Looking at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC is better then looking at the web3.js docs (at least in some cases) for Nethereum